# Bad state: type '_SpecialTypeMirror' is not a subtype of type 'ClassMirror' in type cast

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I'm trying to run the aqueduct's command to generate the DB.

```
aqueduct db generate
```

but I always receive this error:

```
Bad state: type '_SpecialTypeMirror' is not a subtype of type 'ClassMirror' in type cast
```

I'm using the model like this:
import 'package:aqueduct/aqueduct.dart';
import 'package:controle_rural_api/models/Farm.dart';

class User extends ManagedObject implements _User{}

```
class _User {

  @primaryKey
  int id;
  String otherThings;
  bool active;

  ManagedSet<Farm> farms;
}
```

That is the complete error:

```
*** Uncaught error
    Bad state: type '_SpecialTypeMirror' is not a subtype of type 'ClassMirror' in type cast
  **** Stacktrace
  * #0      EntityBuilder._getTableDefinitionForType (package:aqueduct/src/db/managed/builders/entity_builder.dart:236:16)
  * #1      new EntityBuilder (package:aqueduct/src/db/managed/builders/entity_builder.dart:16:31)
  * #2      new DataModelBuilder.<anonymous closure> (package:aqueduct/src/db/managed/builders/data_model_builder.dart:7:42)
  * #3      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:414:29)
  * #4      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:219:19)
  * #5      new DataModelBuilder (package:aqueduct/src/db/managed/builders/data_model_builder.dart:7:71)
  * #6      new ManagedDataModel.fromCurrentMirrorSystem (package:aqueduct/src/db/managed/data_model.dart:46:9)
  * #7      MigrationBuilderExecutable.execute (<data:application/dart>:13:557)
  * <asynchronous suspension>
  * #8      main (<data:application/dart>:9:35)
  * <asynchronous suspension>
  * #9      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:296:32)
  * #10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
  ****
```

Don't look be anything about my code, but I can't generate the code, What can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. Was in the *generics*.

In the `class User extends ManagedObject implements _User{}` I forgot the type, so should be like this: `class User extends ManagedObject<_User> implements _User{}`